# How can I check if I said one of the words contained in a list using speech_recognizer

Tags: python, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm trying to create a little program which should print something if in what I say (not only one word but a phrase) (using speech_recognizer) there is  a word which is  contained in a list of words (word_list). Also the output should change if I say one word or another so I need to check exactly which word is it.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

word_list = ['Giotto', 'Raffaello', 'Michelangelo']

recognizer_instance = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("I'm listening...")
    audio = recognizer_instance.listen(source)
    print('Printing what I heard...')

try:
    text = recognizer_instance.recognize_google(audio, language='it-IT')
    print(text)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

this is my code at the moment and I can't figure out how to check if one of the words contained in the text variable is in my word_list

Comment: Do you simply want to check if what you said is inside that list or is it important which word inside that list it was?

Comment: I also need to know which one is it

Comment: can you give an example on what you would want to achieve if  for example `text = 'Giotto'` ?

Comment: @EliranTurgeman my goal was that to build a proram which stay active and listen ( for example during a class lecture ) and when any of the words is said it prints the bio of that ( in this case I did with some artists ) artist

Comment: Look at the edit I made to my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to check if what you said is in the list you can use:

```
if text in word_list:
    #Some logic
```

this will return `True` if the variable's `text` content is inside `word_list`.

EDIT:
You can define a dictionary instead of a list and store the bio of each artist like that:

```
artists_bio = {'artist1': 'artist1 bio', 'artist2': 'artist2 bio'...}
```

Then in order to print this bio if the recognizer heard the matching word you can use:

```
if text in artist_bio.keys():
    print(artist_bio[text])
```

EDIT2 :

if your text is an entire sentence you could first split it and then use same logic as before.

```
list_text = text.split(' ')
for text in list_text:
    if text in artist_bio.keys():
        print(artist_bio[text])
```

Comment: It kinda helped me but it works only if I say just one of those words... otherwise it doesnt... But if that word is inside a phrase or within other words it doesnt work ....